# Problem involving complex conjugate

Tags: complex-numbers

I have the equation: 
$$3z-\bar{z}=2-3i$$

First I write this as: 
$$3(x+yi)-(x-yi) = 2-3i$$
$$3x-3yi-x+yi = 2-3i$$
$$2x+4yi = 2-3i$$

Now the following must be true: 
$$2x = 2\quad\mbox{and}\quad 4y = -3$$

So $x = 1$, and $y=\textstyle\dfrac{-3i}{4}$

Thus
$$z=1-\textstyle\dfrac{3i}{4}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You are justified in equating the real and imaginary parts on the two sides of the equation.

Comment: It is correct. Only note that you have a typo in the third line. $=3x-3yi-\cdots$ should read $=3x+3yi-\cdots$

Answer (score 1):

Right idea, two small errors.

In line 3 the first minus sign should be a plus sign:
$$3x+3yi-x+yi=2-3i$$
but that was just a typo. Farther down where you wrote
$$y=\frac{-3i}4$$
you meant
$$y=\frac{-3}4.$$

Answer (score 1):

It is correct, but you can do it in a slicker way: conjugate and find
$$
3\bar{z}-z=2+3i
$$
But the original equation says $\bar{z}=3z-2+3i$, so, substituting gives
$$
9z-6+9i-z=2+3i
$$
that becomes
$$
8z=8-6i
$$
that is,
$$
z=1-\frac{3}{4}i
$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct.  You can check you work by plugging the $z$ you found back into the original equation.
$$3\left(1-\frac{3i}{4}\right)-\left(1+\frac{3i}{4}\right)=2-3i\\3-\frac{9i}{4}-1-\frac{3i}{4}=2-3i\\2-\frac{12i}{4}=2-3i\\2-3i=2-3i.$$
So your $z=1-\frac{3i}{4}$ is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps
$$ 3z-\overline{z}=2-3i $$
$$ 3(x+yi)-(x-yi)=2-3i $$
$$ 3x+3yi-x+yi=2-3i $$
$$ 2x+4yi=2-3i $$
Therefore, 
$$ x=1\quad\mbox{and}\quad y=-\frac34 $$
Which implies that
$$ z=1-\frac34i$$